# Can a jew buy pepperoni/sausage pizza for a non-jew

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, gifts

Can a Jew buy (for his own money) pepperoni/sausage pizza for his non-jewish employee as a treat/tip?
For example in honor of the jew's birthday

(meat an milk (that was heated together is forbidden for pleasure)